# RDLC Report Error: Data retrieval failed for the subreport IIS Config

Tags: c#, iis, rdlc

I have 2 servers running the same code :

```
        localReport.LoadSubreportDefinition("ReportHeader", new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports/ReportHeaderLandscape.rdlc")));
        localReport.SubreportProcessing += reportHeader_SubreportProcessing;
        if (subReportProcessing != null)
            localReport.SubreportProcessing += subReportProcessing;
```

and the following code for data retrieval :

```
            CompanyHandler companyHandler = new CompanyHandler();
            CompanyInfoRemote[] companyInfo = companyHandler.GetCompanyInfo();
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSetCompanyInfo", companyInfo));
```

The code works well on server A, but fails to run on server B with following error:

> Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'ReportHeader', located at: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Reports\Reports\ReportHeader.rdlc.
> Please check the log files for more information

I don't know where to find the logs (there's no Reporting Services folder under sql server installation path). I think it's related to an iis configuration or folder security issue.

Comment: You can compare the web.config of the two servers to find out where the configuration is different. But the most important thing is to ensure that the application in serverB can successfully connect to the database, and the report cannot be generated if no data is retrieved. The log file is located inLogFiles under  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: hello ,thanks for your help. In fact the report itself is getting data but not the subreport. Concerning the config file , i copied the file from ServerA to serverB !